# Stabliser of a primitive action has no non-trivial normal subgroup.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/O'Nan-Scott_theorem

Here it says that the stabliser is a maximal subgroup of $G$ (which I understand why) containing no non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$, why is that?

Suppose $G_a$ contains $N$ where $N\lhd G$, then $G=HN$ for some subgroup $H$, then $H$ is transitive and hence primitive. What else can I say? what leads to a contradiction so we can't have $N$ non-trivial?

One extra question is that how is this statement connected to minimal normal subgroups in the proof of the O'Nan-Scott theorem?

Comment: So the stabilizer of $a$ contains a transitive group $H$ and hence, $G_a$ acts transitively. In particular, it can send $a$ everywhere, which contradicts the fact that it's the stabilizer of $a$.

Comment: $G_a$ contains $N$, but why does $G_a$ contain $H$?

Comment: I confused $G_a$ and $G$...

Comment: A normal subgroup in a stabilizer is in all stabilizers, hence is in the kernel of the action.

Comment: does the kernel of a primitive action have to be trivial?

Comment: If you want a faithful action, then yes. The point is that the action of $G$ and $G/N$ is exactly the same, so there's no harm in only considering faithful actions.